# Scripted Dashboard in Grafana with opentsdb as the source

Tags: opentsdb, grafana

I want to create a scripted dashboard that takes one OpenTSDB metric as the datasource. On the Grafana website, I couldn't find any example. I hope I can add some line like:

```
metric = 'my.metric.name'
```

into the JavaScript code, and than I can access the dashboard on the fly.

```
var rows = 1;
var seriesName = 'argName';

if(!_.isUndefined(ARGS.rows)) {
  rows = parseInt(ARGS.rows, 10);
}

if(!_.isUndefined(ARGS.name)) {
  seriesName = ARGS.name;
}

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

  dashboard.rows.push({
    title: 'Scripted Graph ' + i,
    height: '300px',
    panels: [
      {
        title: 'Events',
        type: 'graph',
        span: 12,
        fill: 1,
        linewidth: 2,
        targets: [
          {
            'target': "randomWalk('" + seriesName + "')"
          },
          {
            'target': "randomWalk('random walk2')"
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  });

}

return dashboard;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. But I just figured it out and hopefully post here will benefit somebody.

The script is here. Access the dashboard on the fly with:
http://grafana_ip:3000/dashboard/script/donkey.js?name=tsdbmetricname

```
/* global _ */

/*
 * Complex scripted dashboard
 * This script generates a dashboard object that Grafana can load. It also takes a number of user
 * supplied URL parameters (in the ARGS variable)
 *
 * Return a dashboard object, or a function
 *
 * For async scripts, return a function, this function must take a single callback function as argument,
 * call this callback function with the dashboard object (look at scripted_async.js for an example)
 */



// accessible variables in this scope
var window, document, ARGS, $, jQuery, moment, kbn;

// Setup some variables
var dashboard;

// All url parameters are available via the ARGS object
var ARGS;

// Intialize a skeleton with nothing but a rows array and service object
dashboard = {
  rows : [],
};

// Set a title
dashboard.title = 'From Shrek';

// Set default time
// time can be overriden in the url using from/to parameters, but this is
// handled automatically in grafana core during dashboard initialization
dashboard.time = {
  from: "now-6h",
  to: "now"
};

var rows = 1;
var metricName = 'argName';

//if(!_.isUndefined(ARGS.rows)) {
//  rows = parseInt(ARGS.rows, 10);
//}

if(!_.isUndefined(ARGS.name)) {
  metricName = ARGS.name;
}

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

  dashboard.rows.push({
    title: metricName,
    height: '300px',
    panels: [
      {
        title: metricName,
        type: 'graph',
        span: 12,
        fill: 1,
        linewidth: 2,
        targets: [
          {
              "aggregator": "avg",
              "downsampleAggregator": "avg",
              "errors": {},
              "metric":ARGS.name,
              //"metric": "search-engine.relevance.latency.mean",
              "tags": {
                "host": "*"
              }
          }
        ],
        tooltip: {
          shared: true
        }
      }
    ]
  });
}


return dashboard;
```

Comment: Click the checkbox at the top left of the answer :)